# Wordpress: Infinite Scroll Plugin

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been messing around with a few Wordpress Plugin's for my website. In order for the Infinite Scroll to work, I must know the correct selectors. Could someone help me find the correct selectors? I've tried so many different combos but I've failed many times :(

```
</article><div class="mh-loop-pagination clearfix">
<nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
<h2 class="screen-reader-text">Posts navigation</h2>
<div class="nav-links"><span aria-current='page' class='page-numbers current'>1</span>
<a class='page-numbers' href='https://www.test.com/page/2/'>2</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="https://www.test.com/page/2/">&raquo;</a></div>
```

Navigation Selector: (The selector containing your theme's navigation)

Next Selector: (The link to the next page with content)

Item Selector: (The selector containing a single post or product)

Content Selector: (The selector containing your theme's content)

I'm pretty sure that's all the code that is needed in order to find the selectors. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Which plugin are you currently using?

Comment: I'm using YITH Infinite Scrolling. Thank you for the reply :)

Comment: P.S: Currently using Jetpack but it has so many modules that I don't need or want to use. It also kills my page score speeds because of all of the unnecessary modules.

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? https://yithemes.com/docs-plugins/yith-infinite-scrolling/02-settings.html#setting1